# Detect if a session variable exist after front-end user logs into SharePoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

Is there a JavaScript object, method or property that I can use to detect if a specific SharePoint session variable exist, after a font-end user log's into SharePoint?

The following seems to work..

```
<SharePoint:Delegate runat="server" ControlId="MyDelegateControlTest" Id="MyDelegateControlTest">
<template_Controls>
<script type="text/javascript">var mvar='hello'; console.log('hello world');</script>
</template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

But the minute I try to store a session variable...

```
<SharePoint:Delegate runat="server" ControlId="MyDelegateControlTest" Id="MyDelegateControlTest">
<template_Controls>
<script type="text/javascript">var mvar='<%= Session["demo"]%>'; console.log('hello world');</script>
</template_Controls>
</SharePoint:DelegateControl>
```

...I get an error on my page that says "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DelegateControl does not haev a public property names script"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since session variables are a server side object, the only way to read them from javascript on client side would be to response the session value into the page as a javascript variable.  You could do this with a delegate control in your master page and then have your javascript check for the variable.

EDIT:
On your front end of the delegate, add a script block that looks something like below:

`<script type="text\javascript">
var mySessionVar = '<%= Session["mySessionVar "] %>';
</script>`

You should then be able to access mySessionVar in your javascript code elsewhere.

Comment: So if I have a delegate control set on my master template, how do a call a SharePoint session variable from within it? I am assuming that the delegate control will only be available, after the front-end user log's in?  This is all new to me.  Thanks

Comment: I tried implementing this solution but I get an error that stats "Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DelegateControl does not have a public property names script.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I would highly suggest you deploy this as a feature and not just modify the master page.  Your delegate control is just a link to a UserControl in your solution and the UserControl actually contains the javascript.  If you are just going to use a customized master page, you can drop that javascript snippet into your master page.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation on this @danda1man  I think what I can leave from here today is knowing that SharePoint designer does not like to access session variables directly and that variables coming from the server should be handled/modified/checked/packaged all through visual studio first.  Thank you!